# What is relationship betweeen Node and Namespaces in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Relationship between cluster and namespaces : - Namespaces are in cluster
Relationship between cluster and node  :- Nodes are in cluster
Relationship between pod and namespaces :- Pods run under namespace
Relationship between pod and Node : - pods can run on node.

If I want relationship for node and pods , it can be obtained by command :- **kubectl get pod -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS:.status.phase,NODE:.spec.nodeName --all-namespaces**

How to get relationship between node and namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear. But, lets try...

There is no such relation (in terms of relation). Resources in namespaces can be located on different nodes.

---

If your question about querying resources, use `--field-selector` option.

```
kubectl get pods -all-namespaces \ 
 --field-selector=metadata.namespace!=default,spec.nodeName==minikube
```

- or export information in json and filter with `jq`
- or export information in text and filter with `grep`
- or export in ... and filter with ...

---

or you want to show namespace with node?

```
kubectl get pod --all-namespaces \ 
   -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace,NODE:.spec.nodeName
```